# How to write prototype function for object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

is it possible to make something like this ?

```
let foo = {}, bar = {name : "carl"};
foo.isNotEmpty && "foo is not empty" // FALSE
bar.isNotEmpty && "bar is not empty"; // TRUE


Object.prototype.isNotEmpty = function (){
 return Object.keys(_argument_here).length == 0;
}
```

I don't know how to use object (in this case foo and bar) in my prototype method. Also i want to use it like property not a function, otherwise it looks like this

```
foo.isNotEmpty() && "foo is not empty"
```

I prefer first way but if its not possible second way is okay too.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

> I don't know how to use object (in this case foo and bar) in my prototype method.

You'd use `this` within the function.

***But***:

1. **Never, ever, ever** add enumerable properties to `Object.prototype` (which is what `Object.prototype.isNotEmpty = ...` does). You'll break a huge amount of code that assumes that `for-in` on `{}` won't see any properties to visit / `Object.keys({})` will return an empty array. If you really want to do it, use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) and don't set `enumerable` to `true` (the default is `false`, so if you just leave it off, you're good).
2. Even adding non-enumerable properties to `Object.prototype` is generally strongly discouraged, because of potential conflicts with expected "own" properties of objects.
3. You need to add it before you call it. In your code, you're trying to access it before you've added it.
4. To get the result you want without using `()`, you need to define the function as a property getter (more on that below).

So you *could* do this (with a non-getter function):

```js
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "isNotEmpty", {
    value: function (){
        return Object.keys(this).length == 0;
    },
    configurable: true
});

let foo = {}, bar = {name : "carl"};
console.log(foo.isNotEmpty());
console.log(bar.isNotEmpty());
```

...or if you want a getter:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "isNotEmpty", {
    get: function (){
        return Object.keys(this).length == 0;
    },
    configurable: true
});

let foo = {}, bar = {name : "carl"};
console.log(foo.isNotEmpty);
console.log(bar.isNotEmpty);
```

**But** generally it would be better to have your own function (within a scoping construct [not shown] so you're not defining a global):

```js
function isNotEmpty(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length == 0;
}

let foo = {}, bar = {name : "carl"};
console.log(isNotEmpty(foo));
console.log(isNotEmpty(bar));
```

Comment: Thanks for your tips, i think it'll be better if i can define a helper function which checks object is empty or not, right ?

Comment: @Nezih: Yes. Also note that `Object.keys` only checks for *enumerable*, *own* properties. So if the object you're checking has any non-enumerable own properties, you'll still think it's empty when it isn't.

Comment: According to Kanstantsin Kamkou's answer. It works pretty good. What do you think ?

Comment: @Nezih: I think that answer is wrong, because generic objects like the ones you're using don't have a `length` property. (But that's what I meant about a "getter" in my answer above.) I refer you to the two working examples above. Separately: In my earlier comment, I forgot to point you at a function: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`. That gives you what `Object.keys` gives you *plus* "own" non-enumerable properties, as long as they're strings. (If you have Symbol-named properties, you'd also need `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`.)

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.defineProperty(
  Object.prototype, 'isNotEmpty', {
   get: function() {
     return this.length > 0;
   }
  }
);

const a = 'test';
console.log(a.isNotEmpty); // true
```

As mentioned before, javascript is a strange language, please do not pollute prototypes.

Comment: Thats what i'm talking about. Thank you.

Comment: Generic objects such as the ones in the OP's question have no `length` property.

Comment: strange comments you have. first of all js has no generic objects. objects in js... are also not objects. polluting prototype assuming to detect the type somehow, for example: _.isString(this) or Array.isArray() and so on.

Comment: @KanstantsinKamkou: `{}` is commonly called a generic object (as opposed to the result of `new Date` or similar). And again: They don't have a `length`. If you actually *ran* the code above with the OP's examples, you'd find it doesn't work. Rather than calling the comment strange and nit-picking terminology, you might actually pay attention to the gist of what it's saying. (And I'm afraid the entire second half of your comment ["polluting" onward] is completely unclear in English.)

Comment: Plain objects (maybe that is what you called `generic object`) are those who has no prototype or the prototype is null. i.e. `Object.getPrototypeOf(new Date())` and `Object.getPrototypeOf({})`. Things you're mentioned I'm not familiar with. Sorry.  I don't want to continue this topic. Thank you.

Comment: Your call, you can leave an incorrect answer if you like. Again: Try it, with the OP's objects, and it will not work. *"those who has no prototype or the prototype is null"* Those are the same thing. *"i.e. Object.getPrototypeOf(new Date()) and Object.getPrototypeOf({})."* Neither of which is `null`.

Comment: Please check `Object.getPrototypeOf(new Date()).__proto__` and `Object.getPrototypeOf({}).__proto__`. You'll be surprised. (That is my last reply, sorry)

Comment: No, I'm not at all surprised (you might find, if you checked, that I do know a thing or two about JavaScript). And neither of those results supports what you've said above, or the answer shown. (Please also note that if you don't use the `@`, the person you're replying to doesn't receive a notification unless they're the post owner or the only other person to comment. So unless you were trying to avoid my noticing your replies, that's something to use in future.)